# Count of values between other values in a pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a column of a pandas DataFrame that looks like this:

```
1       False
2       False
3       False
4        True
5        True
6       False
7       False
8       False
9       False
10      False
11      True
12      False
```

I would like to get the count of False between the True. Something like this:

```
1      3
2      0
3      5
4      1
```

This is what I've done:

```
counts = []
count = 0
for k in df['result'].index:
    if df['result'].loc[k] == False:
        count += 1
    else:
        counts.append(count)
        count = 0
```

where counts would be the result. Is there a simpler way?

Comment: Why is there a 0 there?

Comment: I'm using it inside another loop, so I added a 0 to reset the count

Comment: Or did you mean line 2 of the result? There it means there is no False between the two Trues

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Group by the cumulative sum of itself and then count the `False` with `sum`:

```
s = pd.Series([False, False, False,  True,  True, False, False, False, False, False,  True, False])

(~s).groupby(s.cumsum()).sum()
#0    3.0
#1    0.0
#2    5.0
#3    1.0
#dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `groupby` function from the `itertools` package to group the False and True values together and append the count to a list.

```
s = pd.Series([False,False,False,True,True,False,False,False,False,False,True,False], 
              index=range(1,13)

from itertools import groupby

out = []
for v,g in groupby(s):
    if not v:  # v is false
        out.append(len(tuple(g)))
    else:      # v is true
        out.extend([0]*(len(tuple(g))-1))


out
[3, 0, 5, 1]
```